# WP Video Fancy box with iFrame not working

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe, video, lightbox

I have tried to implement the WP Video Fancybox plugin into my websites index.php file.

I have several videos on the website that are managed through my options panel and there is a php echo used to call up the videos by their id.

I tried to wrap the iframe div in an anchor and apply an id and shortcode to open the videos, however when I click on the videos a very small (lightbox) pops up with "Null".

I have spent hours trying to solve this but I am a little stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciatted.

Here is a sample of the code taken from my index.php file.

```
<a href="#inline-1" rel="wp-video-lightbox[iframes]">
<div class="box">
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/<?php echo         get_sub_field('video','options'); ?>?  title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=faa723" width="300" height="169" allowFullScreen id="#inline-1"></iframe>
<div class="title">
<?php echo the_sub_field('video_title','options'); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I never used it before but i tried now and my following codes worked fine for me ....
hope these will help you

```
<a href="#inline-1" rel="wp-video-lightbox[iframes]" title="">
<iframe id="#inline-1" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/4896101?portrait=0&amp;color=00f034" width="500" height="375" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for help, Ramesh. I tried wrapping the iframe in an anchor, instead of wrapping the div that wraps the iframe, as you did in your code. Unfortunately it still didn't work. I am wondering whether it might have something to with the php echo in my code, which retrieves different videos?